# Как расставить запятые в сложноподчиненном предложении

Tags: запятые, спп

Как правильно расставить знаки препинания в предложении: «В перечне приведены изделия, на которые должны быть выданы технические данные с указанием(,) с кем они должны быть согласованы»?

Comment: С кем необходимо согласовать техническую документацию к изделиям, приведенным в перечне?

Answer (score 1):

*(1) В перечне приведены изделия, (2) на которые должны быть выданы технические данные с указанием **(о том)**, (3) **с кем они должны быть согласованы**.*

Это СПП с последовательной связью придаточных. Первое придаточное **определительное** (союзное слово "на которые"), а второе **изъяснительное** (союзное слово "с кем"). Указательное слово "о том" факультативное. Запятые ставятся перед придаточными.

Answer (score 0):

Нужна запятая, потому что ‟с кем они должны быть согласованы” – это определительное придаточное, а они обособляются.

Правильно так: В перечне приведены изделия, на которые должны быть выданы технические данные с указанием, с кем они должны быть согласованы.